# Problem on check condition on laravel php

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem on my laravel code. I want to check condition and show up using dd my code here.

```
$ca = floatval($sw->terminal_ca); // $sw->terminal_ca from postgresql type number(8,6) = 0.003480
$max_ca = $this->terminal_ca*(1+($this->tolerance/100)); // $this->terminal_ca from postgresql type number(16,4) = 0.0029
                                                            // $this->tolerance from postgresql type number(16,4) = 20.0000
                                                            

dd(
$ca, 
$max_ca, 
($ca <= $max_ca));
```

but my result here

[image]

not acceptable.
it should be true.
What's wrong on my code?
How can I solve it?

Comment: `var_dump()` these vars to make sure they have the same type. How do you assign these vals?

Comment: @biesior yes it same type here 
var_dump($ca);
var_dump($max_ca);
and result: float(0.00348) float(0.00348)

Comment: @biesior $ca I got from view laravel blade then covert to float using floatval and $max_ca I got from db postgresql and calculate it before using (all calculate value is type number(16,4))

Comment: This may be a case of precision (something along the lines of `$ca` actually being `0.0034800000000001`). It might help if you show the code that assigns these two values.

Comment: @El_Vanja here my assign code


       `code` $ca = floatval($sw->terminal_ca); // $sw->terminal_ca type number(8,6) = 0.003480
        $max_ca = $this->terminal_ca*(1+($this->tolerance/100)); // $this->terminal_ca type number(16,4) = 0.0029
                                                                 // $this->tolerance type number(16,4) = 20.0000`

Comment: Please add new information by editing the question. Comments aren't suitable for multiline content.

Comment: @El_Vanja I already edit.

Comment: Just as I suspected - [precision error](https://3v4l.org/D3Ls6). You should round your values to the same number of decimals before comparison.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thank sir, It ok now if I round it before comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I round it before comparison is ok now. Thank @El_Vanja

```
$ca = round($ca, 6);
$min_ca = round($min_ca, 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have given static values in the controller and it's working fine.
Kindly check your type in the database from where you are fetching data dynamically.

[image]